# How to elegantly overwrite a character in a 2d Java array when the player moves to it?

Tags: java, arrays

I am coding a game in which ‘P’ moves across a 10x10 board picking up ‘doughnuts’ and avoiding ‘walls’. So far, I have gotten everything right but I cannot get the player ‘P’ to overwrite the character '@' when the player moves to the latter's position, in other words ‘eat’ the doughnut.

I have tried to implement it in the `inputManager` method, it works but the problems is that it ‘eats’ the doughnuts in the order in which they have been declared, as opposed to the positon of ‘P’.

Can someone please kindly help me with this aspect?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    //initial player and home positions
    static int playerColumn = 0;
    static int playerRow = 9;
    static int homeColumn = 9;
    static int homeRow = 0;

    //Variable Declaration for Player and Home
    static char player = 'P';
    static char home = 'H';

    //Doughnut Coordinates
    //Doughnut 1
    static int d1C = 5;
    static int d1R = 6;
    //Doughnut 2
    static int d2C = 7;
    static int d2R = 1;
    //Doughnut 3
    static int d3C = 1;
    static int d3R = 4;
    //Doughnut 4
    static int d4C = 2;
    static int d4R = 8;
    //Doughnut 5
    static int d5C = 4;
    static int d5R = 5;

    //Variable Declaration for Doughnuts
    static char d1 = '@';
    static char d2 = '@';
    static char d3 = '@';
    static char d4 = '@';
    static char d5 = '@';

    //Board Dimension Variables
    static final int column = 10;
    static final int row = 10;

    //Board Setup
    static char[][] tenByTen = new char[column][row];

    //counters
    static int moveCounter;
    static int doughnutCounter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            boardManager();
            inputManager();
        }
    }

    public static void boardManager() {

        //iterate through r
        for (int r = 0; r < tenByTen.length; r++) {
            //iterate through c
            for (int c = 0; c < tenByTen[r].length; c++) {

                tenByTen[c][r] = '.';

                tenByTen[3][2] = 'X';
                tenByTen[3][3] = 'X';
                tenByTen[3][4] = 'X';
                tenByTen[3][5] = 'X';
                tenByTen[3][6] = 'X';

                tenByTen[7][2] = 'X';
                tenByTen[7][3] = 'X';
                tenByTen[7][4] = 'X';
                tenByTen[7][5] = 'X';
                tenByTen[7][6] = 'X';

                tenByTen[2][7] = 'X';
                tenByTen[3][7] = 'X';
                tenByTen[4][7] = 'X';
                tenByTen[5][7] = 'X';
                tenByTen[6][7] = 'X';

                //position doughnuts as per coordinates defined at class level
                tenByTen[d1C][d1R] = d1;
                tenByTen[d2C][d2R] = d2;
                tenByTen[d3C][d3R] = d3;
                tenByTen[d4C][d4R] = d4;
                tenByTen[d5C][d5R] = d5;

                //position the player and home accordingly
                tenByTen[playerColumn][playerRow] = player;
                tenByTen[homeColumn][homeRow] = home;

                System.out.print(tenByTen[c][r] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("");

        //User Prompt
        System.out.println("Press 'U' to move up, 'D' to move down, 'L' to move left and 'R' to move right");
        //Move Counter
        System.out.println(moveCounter);
        System.out.println(doughnutCounter);

        // Quit mechanism: valid when player position 'P' is equal to home 'H'
        if (tenByTen[playerColumn][playerRow] == tenByTen[homeColumn][homeRow]) {
            System.out.println("Welcome home and...good bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void inputManager() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        char inputCharacter = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);

        switch (inputCharacter) {
            case 'u':
                if (playerRow == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that move takes you off the board");
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn][playerRow - 1] == 'X') {
                    System.out.println("You cannot go through the wall");
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn][playerRow - 1] == tenByTen[d1C][d1R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d1 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn][playerRow - 1] == tenByTen[d2C][d2R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d2 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn][playerRow - 1] == tenByTen[d3C][d3R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d3 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn][playerRow - 1] == tenByTen[d4C][d4R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d4 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn][playerRow - 1] == tenByTen[d5C][d5R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d5 = '.';
                } else {
                    moveCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                }
                break;
            case 'd':
                if (playerRow == 9) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that move takes you off the board");
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn][playerRow + 1] == 'X') {
                    System.out.println("You cannot go through the wall");
                }  else if (tenByTen[playerColumn][playerRow + 1] == tenByTen[d1C][d1R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d1 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn][playerRow + 1] == tenByTen[d2C][d2R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d2 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn][playerRow + 1] == tenByTen[d3C][d3R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d3 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn][playerRow + 1] == tenByTen[d4C][d4R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d4 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn][playerRow + 1] == tenByTen[d5C][d5R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d5 = '.';
                } else {
                    moveCounter++;
                    playerRow = ++playerRow;
                }
                break;
            case 'l':
                if (playerColumn == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that move takes you off the board");
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn - 1][playerRow] == 'X') {
                    System.out.println("You cannot go through the wall");
                }  else if (tenByTen[playerColumn - 1][playerRow] == tenByTen[d1C][d1R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d1 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn - 1][playerRow] == tenByTen[d2C][d2R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d2 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn - 1][playerRow] == tenByTen[d3C][d3R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d3 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn - 1][playerRow] == tenByTen[d4C][d4R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d4 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn - 1][playerRow] == tenByTen[d5C][d5R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d5 = '.';
                }else {
                    moveCounter++;
                    playerColumn = --playerColumn;
                }
                break;
            case 'r':
                if (playerColumn == 9) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that move takes you off the board");
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn + 1][playerRow] == 'X') {
                    System.out.println("You cannot go through the wall");
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn + 1][playerRow] == tenByTen[d1C][d1R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d1 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn + 1][playerRow] == tenByTen[d2C][d2R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d2 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn + 1][playerRow] == tenByTen[d3C][d3R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d3 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn + 1][playerRow] == tenByTen[d4C][d4R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d4 = '.';
                } else if (tenByTen[playerColumn + 1][playerRow] == tenByTen[d5C][d5R]) {
                    doughnutCounter++;
                    playerRow = --playerRow;
                    d5 = '.';
                }else {
                    moveCounter++;
                    playerColumn = ++playerColumn;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please ensure you enter the correct character: 'U', 'D', 'L', or 'R'");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are switching the value of the initial `char`, (named `d1/2/3/4/5`), instead of changing the value **inside the array**, at one of the positions you declared:

```
tenByTen[d1C][d1R] = ".";
```

or..

```
tenByTen[d2C][d2R] = ".";
```

etc...

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response MordechayS

Comment: @ChizzyMeka Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted